# How to wait till a function is completely executed when multiple objects call a function in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have an architecture where I have to call a local function to display an Image and then in the background need to upload the image to server so that once the Uploading is finished I can remove the local path used for displaying the image.

Functions

`DidCmpletePickingImage()` , `DisplayImageUsingLocalPath()` , `UploadImageToServer()` and `RemoveImageFromLocal()`.

These are the activities. Now i have option to upload multiple images.

This is my current approach. I pick an array of images from and call The function to show them using local path.

```
for (NSInteger i = 0;i < photos.count ; i ++){

                UIImage *img = photos[i];
                img = [self imageWithImage:img scaledToWidth:400];
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.40);
                [self showLocally:imageData img:img];
            }
```

After they are showed I start uploading them to server on background thread

```
-(void) showLocally:(NSData *)imageData img:(UIImage *)img{

    // Code for showing it using temp path.

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        [self fileUpload:img];
    });
}
```

Then using the background thread File is uploaded to the server using AFNetwork and then after I get a  response I call remove local file path.

But when I do this calling on Background all the images are being simultaneously calling `fileUpload` method and doing it `concurrently` which is increasing load on server. How can I block a call of the function till a the previous object which called the function is completely executed ?

Comment: you can use recursive calling here, where function call after completing one task, set bool value for final  (check is last task) then  return to block call or trigger delegate or publish notifcation

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at using NSOperationQueue in conjunction with maxConcurrentOperationCount -- limiting the number of operations that can occur all at once.

Here's a small example of what I mean:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nullable) NSOperationQueue *imageUploaderQ;
- (void)_randomOperationWithDelayOutputtingInteger:(NSInteger)intToOutput;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageUploaderQ = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    // you can experiment with how many concurrent operations you want here
    self.imageUploaderQ.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
        [self.imageUploaderQ addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self _randomOperationWithDelayOutputtingInteger:index];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)_randomOperationWithDelayOutputtingInteger:(NSInteger)intToOutput {
    // simulating taking some time to upload
    // don't ever explicitly call sleep in your actual code
    sleep(2);
    NSLog(@"Integer output = %li", intToOutput);
}


@end
```

Here are links to Apple's documentation on

[NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue)

[maxConcurrentOperationCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue/1414982-maxconcurrentoperationcount)

Comment: Thank you for linking these. I will check them as they seem like pretty useful links. But in meantime I actually managed to figure out a way to handle the operations using `dispatch_semaphore_wait` and `dispatch_semaphore_signal`

Comment: The above technique is much better than using semaphores.